# What is the difference between bonpow and and alpha.centrality in R igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I have calculated metrics for Bonacich centrality of the nodes of an undirected graph using alpha.centrality and bonpow package in R. I've used the default settings in both the packages and when I calcuated the correlation from the two packages, it was -0.97. The power exponent in both the cases was the default i.e. 1. 
The bonpow package clearly mentions that "positive values (of exponent) imply that vertices become more powerful as their alters become more powerful" . Is the opposite true in the alpha.centrality case? I want to know this because alpha.centrality allows us to include weights (which I want to use) while bonpow does not.

Comment: Those functions calculate different things. Have you checked the help sections?

Comment: @Chris. Thanks. I've looked it up and if I got it right bonpow seems to be based on the 1987 paper while alpha centrality is on the 2001 paper by Bonacich and Lloyd.